# problem with move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, roslaunch, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control a bot with a lidar. When i run the launch files to switch on the lidar and obtain the cmd_vel values from rosserial based on odometry data, the cmd_vel is being published by the move_base.launch file. But, when i run the navigation stack which uses this data, I get an error that says-" THe bot cannot move forward". A little debugging tells me that the navigation stack subscribes to cmd_vel from move_base. But, the cmd_vel is not being output by the launch files itself. How to solve this problem?q

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191162/problem-with-move_base/) by [arvind](https://answers.ros.org/users/15001/arvind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics such as cmd_vel are not published/subscribed to by launch files, they are (or should be) published/subscribed to by nodes. Try looking at your nodes and see what they publish (and what they don't).

---

Originally posted by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) with karma: 101 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0